# Redirect to next ID in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know how do I redirect to next ID in my model?
Thanks

```
def update
  @pedido = Pedido.find(params[:id])

  if @pedido.update(processado: 1)
    redirect_to "/pedidos/" + #{NextId}
    #redirect_to root_path 
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @pedido.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: if your model `Pedido` is sorted by `id` or `created_at`(which I think it is), you just need to do something like `next_id = Pedido.where("id > ?", @pedido.id).first.id`

Comment: Awesome ... this work, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
redirect_to pedido_path(@pedido.id + 1)
```

Comment: just be careful with this approach, at some point record with id = `@pedido.id + 1` could not exist anymore.